# scikitlearn - memory error during MiniBatchKMeans clustering after HashingVectorizer

Tags: python, scikit-learn, out-of-memory, cluster-analysis, large-data

my goal is to perform **clustering of texts** from a dataset of **millions of rows**, where each row is a string of words, which doesn't correspond to a proper document, but rather to a list of "keywords". The idea is that **each row represents a Twitter user with the list of keywords taken from his/her tweets**, here is an example of a row:

```
"remove United States District Attorney Carmen Ortiz office overreach case Aaron Swartz"
```

Here is my code:

```
from __future__ import print_function
from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import HashingVectorizer
from sklearn.cluster import MiniBatchKMeans
from time import time
import csv

# LOAD CSV
print("Loading Dataset from a CSV...")
csvinputfile = '...'
t = time()
dataset = open(csvinputfile, 'r')
print("done in %0.3fs" % (time() - t))
print("")

# TERM OCCURRENCES
print("Calculating Term Occurrences...")
t = time()
vectorizer = HashingVectorizer(n_features=300000, stop_words=None, alternate_sign=False, norm='l2', binary=False)
x = vectorizer.fit_transform(dataset)
print("done in %0.3fs" % (time() - t))
print("")

# CLUSTERING
print("MiniBatchKMeans Clustering...")
t = time()
km = MiniBatchKMeans(n_clusters=10000, init='k-means++', n_init=1, init_size=10000, batch_size=10000, verbose=False)
clusters = km.fit(x)
print("done in %0.3fs" % (time() - t))
print("")
```

My problem is that when it comes to do clustering I get a **Memory Error**:

```
MiniBatchKMeans Clustering...
Traceback (most recent call last):
File ".../cluster-users.py", line 32, in <module> clusters = km.fit(x)
File ".../python2.7/site-packages/sklearn/cluster/k_means_.py", line 1418, in fit init_size=init_size)
File ".../python2.7/site-packages/sklearn/cluster/k_means_.py", line 684, in _init_centroids x_squared_norms=x_squared_norms)
File ".../python2.7/site-packages/sklearn/cluster/k_means_.py", line 79, in _k_init centers = np.empty((n_clusters, n_features), dtype=X.dtype)
MemoryError
[Finished in 22.923s]
```

I am quite new to **python** and **scikitlearn** so I don't understand really well what is happening, but I assume it is because, since I am dealing with a large dataset, the clustering phase is trying to load the huge matrix of n_samples and n_features into memory.

A part from that error, which I don't understand since I thought that **MiniBatchKMeans** and **HashingVectorizer** was what could help against memory limits, I also don't really know what are the **best parameters** to use (I followed the scikitlearn tutorial for KMeans and MiniBatchKMeans for clustering texts as a base, you can find it here http://scikit-learn.org/stable/auto_examples/text/document_clustering.html#sphx-glr-auto-examples-text-document-clustering-py).

Things to remember:

- I **cannot use** any **Machine Learning** or **NLP** or **MapReduce** like techniques
- The **clusters** needs to somehow **represent users with similar interests**, therefore similar keywords usage

So my question is: how can I **fix the memory error**? And if someone has some **hints** on how to properly set up the clustering, or if my approach is wrong, that would also be nice.

Comment: Dont load the all the data at once into the program. You are using MiniBatchKMeans, so make use of  its `partial_fit()` method. Load small chunk of data, transform it using HashingVectorizer and pass that to `partial_fit()`.

Comment: Will I have different results from doing the hashing vectorization on all the data, and then passing the resulting matrix to minibatchkmeans in chunks? I am asking this because I've tried it and as a result in "km.labels_" I only found the last chunk of data I partial fitted.

Comment: @VivekKumar Ohh another thing: if I want to add a dimensionality reduction step, is it ok to add it right after the HashingVectorizer phase or is it conceptually/logically wrong? So if I am understanding right I have to:
for each chunk of raw data -> do hashing vectorization -> do dimensionality reduction -> do minibatchkmeans -> save results of that chunk -> repeat for another chunk until I process the whole dataset

Comment: If you want to reduce dimensions, why not start with lower n_features in HashingVectorizer in the first place?

Comment: since my data are short texts, shouldn't be the number of features equals to the number of possible unique words? Otherwise I will lose information, at least this is what I understood, and then in order to lower the computational cost I perform dimensionality reduction.

Answer (score 1):

A row containing text like this, "remove United States District Attorney Carmen Ortiz office overreach case Aaron Swartz" is indeed `dirty`.

To fix the memory error, ensure the following points stand true;

- Are all the keywords in a row relevant? If not, try to reduce them by removing stop words, punctuation marks etc.
- Focus on aggregating relevant keywords from the text. You can create a list of such keywords.
- Look for the `regex` library in python. It can help you with data cleaning.
- To determine the best parameters, look for terms like `within cluster sums of squares` or the `average silhouette` or `gap statistic`.

Clustering is not some kind of `dark-magic` that will yield results. If you input garbage it will yield garbage.

P.S. Please do not create new questions for the same problem. There is already another [similar question that you've asked recently](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52115697/short-text-clustering-with-large-dataset-user-profiling). Unless, the two questions are radically different, create a new question otherwise state it clearly in your post, how is this question different from the previous question.

Comment: The strings are already cleaned from those words. Sorry for the second question, but with this I wanted mainly to address the memory error.