# How to update a csv file based on data from another csv file?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, csv

I have two csv file: `list.csv` `company.csv`

`list.csv` has four columns: *company name*,*info1*, *info2*, *info3* where last three columns are empty and need to be updated based on data from `company.csv`

`company.csv` also has four columns: *company name*,*info1*, *info2*, *info3*

So what I want to do is go through `company name` column in `list.csv` and compare and find matching value  in `company.csv`, then update `info` 1 to 3. I searched on Stackoverflow and it seems like I can use `merge` to solve this problem.

But another problem is that some of the `company name` in `list.csv` has misspelling.

For example, **Stackoverflow** is misspelled as **Stackobarflow** in `list.csv`. Therefore, instead of look for exactly the same `company name` in `company.csv`, I want to search for `company name` that has the same first four letters and regard it as same company.

How can I do this? I know I have to upload some codes when asking for a help but I have no idea how to do this in python

---

**EDIT**

**list.csv**

| Company Name | info1 | info2 | info3 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Faceboook | N/A | N/A | N/A |
| Stakoverflow | N/A | N/A | N/A |

**company.csv**

| Company Name | info1 | info2 | info3 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Facebook | 10 | 20 | SNS |
| Stackoverflow | 20 | 20 | Coding |

**result.csv**

| Company Name | info1 | info2 | info3 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Faceboook | 10 | 10 | SNS |
| Stakoverflow | 20 | 20 | Coding |

Comment: Can you please edit your question and put there example input dataframes and expected output?

Comment: @AndrejKesely I edited question and put example dataframes and expected output

Answer (score 0):

For handling misspelled companies, you would have to use something like a Levenstein distance, or a similar approach. Quick googling gave me [this SO post with a comparison of different methods](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6690739/high-performance-fuzzy-string-comparison-in-python-use-levenshtein-or-difflib). There are packages available for Levenshtein distance, no need to implement it yourself.

It all depends on the size of your files. I would probably use `merge` first to handle the case where company names match exactly, and then check the Levenshtein distance for the remainder. If the files are small, then there is no need for the first step, just do Levenshtein for all vs all. One approach is to create a rectangular matrix of distances, with rows corresponding to company names from `list.csv`, and columns  - to `company.csv`. Divide the distance by the maximum of string lengths, to normalise it. Pick a (normalised) distance threshold, below which the strings are considered similar.

Answer (score 0):

Supposing you have these dataframes:

df1:

```
   Company Name  info1  info2  info3
0  Non-Existent    NaN    NaN    NaN
1     Faceboook    NaN    NaN    NaN
2  Stakoverflow    NaN    NaN    NaN
```

df2:

```
    Company Name  info1  info2   info3
0       Facebook     10     20     SNS
1  Stackoverflow     20     20  Coding
```

Then:

```
df1["tmp"] = df1["Company Name"].str[:3]
df2["tmp"] = df2["Company Name"].str[:3]

df1 = df1.set_index("tmp")
df2 = df2.set_index("tmp")

df1 = df1.fillna(df2).reset_index(drop=True)
print(df1)
```

Prints:

```
   Company Name info1 info2   info3
0  Non-Existent   NaN   NaN     NaN
1     Faceboook    10    20     SNS
2  Stakoverflow    20    20  Coding
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer. As far as I understand, the purpose of the first two lines of the code is to get the first four letters of the company. Then would it be possible to give one more rule something like having first four letters and last two letters?

Comment: And if the some data is already filled in (not NaN) and I want to update it based on the data from `df2`, what can I use instead of `df.fillna`?